# "variable" length initialisation using C preprocessor

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I'm writing some program for a stm32l0 microcontroller.
I define some arrays as global variables:

```
volatile uint32_t     synth_counter  [N_CHANNELS];
volatile uint32_t     synth_pitch    [N_CHANNELS];
volatile uint32_t     synth_envelope [N_CHANNELS];
volatile int_fast8_t  synth_key      [N_CHANNELS];
volatile uint32_t     synth_active   [N_CHANNELS];
volatile uint32_t     synth_state    [N_CHANNELS];
volatile uint32_t     synth_envl_add [N_CHANNELS];
volatile uint32_t     synth_envl_sub [N_CHANNELS];
volatile uint32_t     synth_envl_goal[N_CHANNELS];
volatile int_fast8_t  synth_prev     [N_CHANNELS];
volatile int_fast8_t  synth_next     [N_CHANNELS];

...

         uint8_t      CH_ACTIVE [N_NOTES];
         int_fast8_t  CH_INDEX  [N_NOTES];

volatile uint32_t     PITCH     [N_NOTES];

volatile int8_t       SAMPLE    [N_SAMPLE] = DEFAULT_SAMPLE;
```

As you can see, the size of the array is a constant defined in a header file:

```
#define N_NOTES   97               // = (9 - 1) * 12 + 1

#define N_CHANNELS 12 //EVEN NUMBER
#define N_SAMPLE   256
```

I want those arrays have an initial value which can be overwritten later.
For one of them I could do:

```
volatile int8_t       SAMPLE    [N_SAMPLE] = DEFAULT_SAMPLE;
```

because I know that `N_SAMPLE` will always be 256.
So I could define something like this:

```
#define DEFAULT_SAMPLE \
{ \
    0x7F, 0x7F, 0x7F, 0x7F, 0x7E, 0x7E, 0x7E, 0x7D, \
    0x7D, 0x7C, 0x7B, 0x7A, 0x7A, 0x79, 0x78, 0x76, \
    0x75, 0x74, 0x73, 0x71, 0x70, 0x6E, 0x6D, 0x6B, \
    0x6A, 0x68, 0x66, 0x64, 0x62, 0x60, 0x5E, 0x5C, \
    0x5A, 0x57, 0x55, 0x53, 0x50, 0x4E, 0x4B, 0x49, \
    0x46, 0x44, 0x41, 0x3E, 0x3C, 0x39, 0x36, 0x33, \
    0x30, 0x2D, 0x2A, 0x27, 0x25, 0x22, 0x1E, 0x1B, \
    0x18, 0x15, 0x12, 0x0F, 0x0C, 0x09, 0x06, 0x03, \
    0x00, 0xFC, 0xF9, 0xF6, 0xF3, 0xF0, 0xED, 0xEA, \
    0xE7, 0xE4, 0xE1, 0xDD, 0xDA, 0xD8, 0xD5, 0xD2, \
    0xCF, 0xCC, 0xC9, 0xC6, 0xC3, 0xC1, 0xBE, 0xBB, \
    0xB9, 0xB6, 0xB4, 0xB1, 0xAF, 0xAC, 0xAA, 0xA8, \
    0xA5, 0xA3, 0xA1, 0x9F, 0x9D, 0x9B, 0x99, 0x97, \
    0x95, 0x94, 0x92, 0x91, 0x8F, 0x8E, 0x8C, 0x8B, \
    0x8A, 0x89, 0x87, 0x86, 0x85, 0x85, 0x84, 0x83, \
    0x82, 0x82, 0x81, 0x81, 0x81, 0x80, 0x80, 0x80, \
    0x80, 0x80, 0x80, 0x80, 0x81, 0x81, 0x81, 0x82, \
    0x82, 0x83, 0x84, 0x85, 0x85, 0x86, 0x87, 0x89, \
    0x8A, 0x8B, 0x8C, 0x8E, 0x8F, 0x91, 0x92, 0x94, \
    0x95, 0x97, 0x99, 0x9B, 0x9D, 0x9F, 0xA1, 0xA3, \
    0xA5, 0xA8, 0xAA, 0xAC, 0xAF, 0xB1, 0xB4, 0xB6, \
    0xB9, 0xBB, 0xBE, 0xC1, 0xC3, 0xC6, 0xC9, 0xCC, \
    0xCF, 0xD2, 0xD5, 0xD8, 0xDA, 0xDD, 0xE1, 0xE4, \
    0xE7, 0xEA, 0xED, 0xF0, 0xF3, 0xF6, 0xF9, 0xFC, \
    0xFF, 0x03, 0x06, 0x09, 0x0C, 0x0F, 0x12, 0x15, \
    0x18, 0x1B, 0x1E, 0x22, 0x25, 0x27, 0x2A, 0x2D, \
    0x30, 0x33, 0x36, 0x39, 0x3C, 0x3E, 0x41, 0x44, \
    0x46, 0x49, 0x4B, 0x4E, 0x50, 0x53, 0x55, 0x57, \
    0x5A, 0x5C, 0x5E, 0x60, 0x62, 0x64, 0x66, 0x68, \
    0x6A, 0x6B, 0x6D, 0x6E, 0x70, 0x71, 0x73, 0x74, \
    0x75, 0x76, 0x78, 0x79, 0x7A, 0x7A, 0x7B, 0x7C, \
    0x7D, 0x7D, 0x7E, 0x7E, 0x7E, 0x7F, 0x7F, 0x7F  \
}
```

I can not know this for other arrays.
I would want to create for example a `#define DEFAULT_SYNTH_NEXT` which will become:
`{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, -1}` when `N_CHANNELS` equals 8,
`{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -1}` when `N_CHANNELS` equal 6,
and so on.
Create a `#define DEFAULT_CH_ACTIVE` which is an array filled with `N_NOTES` values of -1.
and so on and so on.

Is it possible, using the C preprocessor to achieve a `#define` which depends on previously defined number in a way described above?
Somehow (recursively?) (iterably?) produce the expected result?

I found an article http://jhnet.co.uk/articles/cpp_magic but this does not look very readable and understandable and I didn't manage to figure it out yet.
I'm hoping for something more clear to read.

I see 2 alternatives to what I want, but they are not ideal:

Alternative 1 is statically defining like:

```
#define DEFAULT_SYNTH_PREV {-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
#define DEFAULT_SYNTH_NEXT {1, 2, 3, 4 ,5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, -1}
```

and so on, but then I have to manually edit it every time I update one of those values.

Alternative 2 is initialising the arrays in the `main()` function, in `for()` loops before entering the main loop.
This is what I'm currently doing,

```
    set_tuning(DEFAULT_TUNING);
    
    for(i=0; i<N_CHANNELS; ++i)
    {
        synth_counter[i] = 0;
        synth_pitch[i] = 0;
        synth_envelope[i] = 0;
        synth_envl_add[i] = 0;
        synth_envl_sub[i] = 0;
        synth_envl_goal[i] = 0;
        synth_active[i] = 0;
        synth_state[i] = ENVL_0;
        if (i==0)
            synth_prev[i] = -1;
        else
            synth_prev[i] = i-1;
        if (i==(N_CHANNELS - 1))
            synth_next[i] = -1;
        else
            synth_next[i] = i+1;
        synth_key[i] = -1;
    }
    for (i=0; i<N_NOTES; ++i)
    {
        CH_ACTIVE[i] = 0;
        CH_INDEX[i] = -1;
    }
```

This does prefill the array with required values but it is less optimal code than the code which prefills predefined variables by copying from FLASH to RAM in the reset handler in the startup code which is included to the project by default:

```
Reset_Handler:  
  ldr   r0, =_estack
  mov   sp, r0          /* set stack pointer */

/* Copy the data segment initializers from flash to SRAM */
  movs  r1, #0
  b  LoopCopyDataInit

CopyDataInit:
  ldr  r3, =_sidata
  ldr  r3, [r3, r1]
  str  r3, [r0, r1]
  adds  r1, r1, #4

LoopCopyDataInit:
  ldr  r0, =_sdata
  ldr  r3, =_edata
  adds  r2, r0, r1
  cmp  r2, r3
  bcc  CopyDataInit
  ldr  r2, =_sbss
  b  LoopFillZerobss
/* Zero fill the bss segment. */
FillZerobss:
  movs  r3, #0
  str  r3, [r2]
  adds r2, r2, #4


LoopFillZerobss:
  ldr  r3, = _ebss
  cmp  r2, r3
  bcc  FillZerobss

/* Call the clock system intitialization function.*/
  bl  SystemInit
/* Call static constructors */
    bl __libc_init_array
/* Call the application's entry point.*/
  bl  main
```

This is why I'm still hoping to be able to "dynamically" `#define` the array initialisers

Comment: Forget the preprocessor. Write a code generator.

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't make a `static unsigned char[]` out of sample and not a pre-processor macro?

Comment: `#define N_NOTES   97               // = (9 - 1) * 12 + 1` - do not do this. If a number makes sense as a result of a math operation, put the math operation into number definition. I have seen some errors with unpleasant consequences where there was a math error like that.

Comment: Answering to the question as asked - it **could** be possible, but it would be a terribly looking code. Sophisticated PP constructs are frown upon, are a nightmare to troubleshoot and produce cryptic errors. Just codegen.

Comment: @Neil - static variable preserves value when out of scope. But these are global variables so always in scope. Global because interrupt handling function has to see them and they represent global state of device. preprocessor macro defines only initial value.

Comment: @SergeyA (9-1)*12-1, yes, true.

Comment: @SergeyA "just codegen" - I was kind of hoping to avoid this in this project as it didn't seem to be complex enough but this might be the solution after all.

Comment: bicyclesonthemoon, You mentioned "N_CHANNELS equals 8, ... when N_CHANNELS equal 6, and so on.".  What are the _realistic_ values possible for  `N_CHANNELS`: 6,8?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica possible values are 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16. Actually realistic values are 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16. Number must be even. At 0 device doesn't do anything. below 6 is useless, above 16 accumulator variable can overflow.

Comment: Have you timed both versions?  Filling the array with a loop might actually be faster than copying it from flash, as well as reducing the size of the image to be flashed.

Comment: Generally, you shouldn't have this kind of non-deterministic behavior in a microcontroller application. Just allocate an array that's large enough to cover the requirements, then ignore parts of it if needed.

Comment: @NateEldredge I did not. But I don't have to. Global data is assumed to be initialised by 0. So if I use the loop, the arrays will be initialised twice: first with 0 before entering main() then again with correct data inside main().

Comment: @Lundin but there is nothing non-deterministic. The values for size are chosen before compiling, and everything next is 100% predictable.

Comment: @bicyclesonthemoon: Yeah.  And even *both initializations together* might be faster than copying from flash.  Some flash is very slow to read.  You won't know unless you time it.  You *also* won't know whether the amount of time taken, even if longer, is actually significant - you might be spending time optimizing something that doesn't need to be optimized.

Comment: @bicyclesonthemoon So chose the size and data before compiling both...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first requirement, you can simply do something like this:

```
#if N_CHANNELS == 8
    #define DEFAULT_SYNTH_NEXT { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, -1 }
#endif

#if N_CHANNELS == 6
    #define DEFAULT_SYNTH_NEXT { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -1 }
#endif
```

and so on.

Not sure how to do the second one.

---

Or, as per @chux's comment, you could do:

```
#if N_CHANNELS == 8
    #define DEFAULT_SYNTH_NEXT { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, -1 }
#elif N_CHANNELS == 6
    #define DEFAULT_SYNTH_NEXT { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -1 }
...
#else
    #error "Unsupported N_CHANNELS value"
#endif
```

Comment: This could be the solution in my specific case as the possible values for `N_CHANNELS` are limited. as mentioned in my previous comment, possible values are 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16.
For all my other arrays I can use "designated initialisers" https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Designated-Inits.htm
`volatile uint32_t     synth_state    [N_CHANNELS] = {[0 ... (N_CHANNELS-1)] = ENVL_0};`

Comment: A `#if ... #elif .... #elif .... #else .... #endif` allows for a `#error "useful message"` in the `#else`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Good idea, thank you.

Comment: With limited `N_CHANNELS`, this is probably the easiest and least-bug-prone solution.

Answer (score 1):

Thats really really ugly, but you can make use of designated initializers:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define VAL(max, x) [(x <= max) ? (x - 1) : 0] = (x <= max) ? x : 1,

#define MAKE_ARRAY(name, max)           \
static_assert((max > 0) && (max < 9));  \
volatile int name[] = {                 \
    VAL(max, 1)                         \
    VAL(max, 2)                         \
    VAL(max, 3)                         \
    VAL(max, 4)                         \
    VAL(max, 5)                         \
    VAL(max, 6)                         \
    VAL(max, 7)                         \
    VAL(max, 8)                         \
    [max - 1] = -1                      \
}

#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Woverride-init"

MAKE_ARRAY(synth, 3);
// More arrays here

#pragma GCC diagnostic pop

int main(void)
{
    size_t size = sizeof(synth) / sizeof(*synth);

    printf("array size = %zu\nvalues = {", size);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf(" %d,", synth[i]);
    }
    printf(" }\n");
    return 0;
}
```

`MAKE_ARRAY(synth, 3)` expands to:

```
static_assert((3 > 0) && (3 < 9));
volatile int synth[] = {[0]=1,[1]=2,[2]=-1,[0]=1,[0]=1,[0]=1,[0]=1,[0]=1};
```

The ouput is:

```
array size = 3
values = { 1, 2, -1, }
```

I'm using

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Woverride-init"
```

to silence the compiler due to the repetition in: `,[0]=1,[0]=1,[0]=1 ...`

Otherwise I get:

```
warning: initialized field overwritten [-Woverride-init]
```

You can also use:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define VAL1 -1
#define VAL2 1
#define VAL3 VAL2, 2
#define VAL4 VAL3, 3
#define VAL5 VAL4, 4
#define VAL6 VAL5, 5
#define VAL7 VAL6, 6
#define VAL8 VAL7, 7

#define MAKE_ARRAY(name, max)           \
static_assert((max > 0) && (max < 9));  \
volatile int name[] = {VAL##max, -1}

MAKE_ARRAY(synth, 3);
// More arrays here

int main(void)
{
    size_t size = sizeof(synth) / sizeof(*synth);

    printf("array size = %zu\nvalues = {", size);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf(" %d,", synth[i]);
    }
    printf(" }\n");
    return 0;
}
```

In this case `MAKE_ARRAY(synth, 3)` expands to:

```
static_assert((3 > 0) && (3 < 9));
volatile int synth[] = {1, 2, -1};
```

But then you can not use:

```
#define NELEMS 3
MAKE_ARRAY(synth, NELEMS);
```

nor

```
enum {NELEMS = 3};
MAKE_ARRAY(synth, NELEMS);
```

while first version allows you to do it.

Answer (score 0):

> I found an article http://jhnet.co.uk/articles/cpp_magic but this does not look very readable and understandable and I didn't manage to figure it out yet.

Rather than untangle how the magic works, you can just use a library with the magic done for you.

Using boost preprocessor:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/arithmetic/dec.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/repetition/enum_shifted.hpp>

#define IOTA_FROM_0(Z_, COUNT_, _) \
    BOOST_PP_DEC(COUNT_)
#define DEFAULT_SYNTH_PREV \
    { -1, BOOST_PP_ENUM_SHIFTED(N_CHANNELS, IOTA_FROM_0, ) }

#define IOTA(Z_, COUNT_, _) COUNT_
#define DEFAULT_SYNTH_NEXT \
    { BOOST_PP_ENUM_SHIFTED(N_CHANNELS, IOTA, ) , -1 }
```

...and yes, boost preprocessor works in C.

This just uses [`BOOST_PP_ENUM_SHIFTED`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/enum_shifted.html), which is almost everything you want.  For your PREV macro, this just adds [`BOOST_PP_DEC`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/dec.html).  Since that saturates at `0` we plug the `-1` in manually (not so different than what you do in your loop, though for the loop case `0-1` does equal -1!)

### Demo

On [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/38e012e156cfac95).